# Probability of getting a red ball when picking 5 from 10 in a bag

Tags: probability

There are 10 balls in the bag, 2 of them are red. We are picking randomly 5 balls from 10, what is the probability that at least one of picken 5 is red?
So far I found out that are $^{10}C_5 = 252 $ possibilties of picking 5 from 10.

Comment: Try answering the simpler question of finding the probability that *none* of them are red.  That would have happened if the first wasn't red and the second wasn't red and...

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to find probability that there are no  red picked and subract that probability from  one, but  I don't know how to do that

Comment: The probability that the first ball wasn't red will be $\frac{8}{10}$ since there are eight not-red balls out of ten available balls.  The probability that the second ball is not red *given that* the first ball was also not red will be $\frac{7}{9}$ since there are seven remaining not-red balls out of nine remaining available balls.  To get the probability that neither the first nor the second ball are red, we multiply these together.  The probability that the first and the second ball are both not red is $\frac{8}{10}\times\frac{7}{9}$.  Continue in this fashion for pulling five balls instead

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer using combinations, there are as you say $\binom{10}{5}=252$ ways of picking five balls irregardless of color (*where order doesn't matter*).  If we want to count the number of ways of picking no red balls (*order not mattering*) there are eight not-red balls of which we want to pick five of them... so... *eight* **choose** *five*... what would our numerator be?

Comment: As a final aside, use whatever notation your teacher uses for the time being, but note that it is far more common on this site and in western culture to see $\binom{n}{r}$ to denote the binomial coefficient counting the number of $r$-element subsets of an $n$ element set.  You might also see $~_nC_r$ or $C(n,r)$ or similar.  Having these in the reverse order like yours as $~_rC_n$ with the smaller on the left is much less common in my experience, not even being listed on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation) as one of the standard options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It says to find the probability of picking at least $1$ red ball. So your total probability is simply, 
$$P(X\geq1)=P(X=1) + P(X=2)$$ 
Now, this is a simply fancy notation for saying it is the sum of the probability that you pick $1$ red ball out of the $5$ and $2$ red balls out of the $5$. Then for $1$ red ball we get, $$P(X=1) = \frac{^2C_1}{^{10}C_5} \;\text{or} \;\frac{\binom21}{\binom {10}{5}}$$ 
And for $2$ red balls we get,
 $$P(X=2) =  \frac{^2C_2}{^{10}C_5}\;\text{or} \;\frac{\binom22}{\binom {10}{5}}$$ The sum of these two gives you your answer.

Comment: This is incorrect.  You neglected to take into consideration what the remaining not-red balls were that were selected.  Note, $X$ could have been $0,1,$ or $2$ and so we would have wanted $Pr(X=0)+Pr(X=1)+Pr(X=2)=1$ but according to your logic this would have been $\dfrac{\binom{2}{0}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}}=\dfrac{4}{252}\neq 1$

Comment: I see your point but I still don't see why $P(X\geq0) = 1$?

Comment: Because however we draw balls, we will have always drawn exactly $0$, exactly $1$, or exactly $2$ red balls.  The probability of the "sure" event is always $1$.  That is one of the basic requirements of being a probability space.

Comment: Oh right, you're right I see my mistake now, I apologize, careless mistake.

Answer (score -1):

It is more common to approach a "getting at least one" style problem by finding the opposite probability as alluded to in my comments above, the probability of "getting less than one" i.e. the probability of getting zero.

To get the probability of having gotten zero red balls, we choose which five not-red balls were selected in $\binom{8}{5}$ ways and divide by the number of ways of selecting five balls in the first place which would be $\binom{10}{5}$

This gives the probability of getting no red balls as being $\dfrac{\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}$ and so the probability of getting at least one red ball is:

$$1 - \frac{\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}$$

We could have also seen this via rule of product for probability.  To have gotten zero red balls means the first ball is not red, the second ball from those remaining is also not red, and so on...  This gives a final answer of getting at least one red ball as being:

$$1 - \frac{8}{10}\times\frac{7}{9}\times\frac{6}{8}\times\frac{5}{7}\times\frac{4}{6}$$

or rewritten with falling factorial notation as $1 - \dfrac{8\frac{5}{~}}{10\frac{5}{~}}$

This could have been arrived at directly as well by finding the probability of getting exactly one red ball and adding this to the probability of getting exactly two red balls as well just as the other answer attempted to do.  To get exactly $k$ red balls, pick which $k$ balls they were and which $5-k$ not-red balls were selected.  Dividing the result by the number of ways of having selected $5$ balls regardless of color we would get then the probability of getting exactly $1$ red ball as being $\dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{4}}{\binom{10}{5}}$ and of getting exactly $2$ red balls as being $\dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}$.  This gives a final answer then of

$$\dfrac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{4}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}$$

This of course equals the same results as we found before.  In larger problems however where we select many more balls and many more red balls were available to have been selected, we can save a great deal of time and tedium by using the earlier approach.

The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) can be used to describe the results of each of these rather cleanly as well.  We have if we have $N$ objects, $K$ of which are special and the remaining $N-K$ of which are not-special, the probability that when choosing $n$ objects that $k$ of the chosen objects are special will be

$$Pr(X=k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

In your problem, $N=10, K=2, n=5$ and we are interested in the cases where $k=1$ or $k=2$.